# ParseKit compile error on Moutain Lion

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, parsekit

I downloaded ParseKit rev 90? from web site. Tried to compile Demo App. First, I got error saying that "No Base SDK is available". It seems to me that SDK10.5 may not be available on Mountain Lion. I changed Base SDK 10.7(which is the oldest what I could find)
Then, I got a lot of errors. They all look similar like

in PKCharacterAssembly.m

```
- (NSString *)description {
............
 [s appendFormat:@"%C", [obj integerValue]];
```

**Format specified type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'NSInteger'(aka long')**

As suggested from Xcode, I changed %C->%ld and so on. Finally, I could launch the demo app. The problem is that it keep parsing grammer forever. 
Is there a way to avoid these errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

I have updated the project to build cleanly under ML. Use head of trunk from Google code:

http://code.google.com/p/parsekit/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I downloaded rev. 129. Tried to compile with Xcode 4.3.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.4.
There were three compile errors.

1.in PkParserFactory.m
Error::Format not a string literal and no format arguments

2. same function as No.1
Error::Control reaches end of non-void function

3.in PkParser.m 
Error::Control reaches end of non-void function

After fixing those errors, I got 30 errors like

in PkToken.h

#if PLATFORM(TWITTER_STATE)
Error :: Missing binary operator before token "(".


Do I need to set same compiler option or something ?

Comment: Update to ParseKit head of trunk, and Xcode 4.4. Should build and run unit tests cleanly now on Lion or Mtn Lion.